# Calling a Blazor method From JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, blazor

I'm experimenting with Blazor in Visual Studio, specifically with calling Blazor code from JavaScript. I'm reasonably confident that I've got all the right libraries in place. However, when I attempt to call my Blazor method with invokeMethodAsync, I get the message "no .net call dispatcher has been set". In my Index.Html file, I have this:

`<script>
 DotNet.invokeMethodAsync("BlazorFour.App", "HelloYou").then(data => alert(data), reason => alert(reason));
</script>`

(It's the alert(reason) that generates the error message)

I've added a class file to my Blazor project and it contains this:

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class HelloWorld
{
[JSInvokable]
public static Task<string> HelloYou()
{
    return Task.FromResult("Hello, ");
}
}
```

I've used all the templates in Visual Studio and the dotnet -new blazor commandline utility to create my start points but get the same message in all of the projects. It's seems likely to me that I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Please, remove both calls to the alert function and tell us if HelloYou is called...

Comment: Tried that and it appears to make no difference: If HelloYou is being called it's in a completely invisible way.

Answer (score 4):

Peter Vogel:
It would be great if you could call Blazor C# methods from your JavaScript code. Right now, that's not quite possible: Simply calling Blazor C# from JavaScript won't work (you'll get a message about a call dispatcher not being available).

What you can do, however, is once your Blazor code is running, call JavaScript code from your C# code. Once you've done that, your JavaScript code can, in turn, call Blazor code.

Hope this solves the problem...

Comment: Actually it does. But you gave me a giggle, too because you're quoting me from an article I wrote about what I (eventually) discovered. It's nice to discover that someone actually reads those articles! Thanks! (and I never pay any attention to who writes those articles, either. I would have done the same thing - hope you get a laugh out of this, too).

Answer (score 3):

**I'm using server-side-blazor**

I was getting js errors
**No .NET call dispatcher has been set**

So yep .. looks like Blazor wasn't initialized..

Not keen on a *timeout* 
.. seems hacky and gives a laggy UI

Not keen on '*call JavaScript code from your C# code. Once you've done that, your JavaScript code can, in turn, call Blazor code.*'
.. again seems hacky

**This works for me ..**

```js
async function myBlazoryFunctionThing() {
    // see https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore@bd65275148abc9b07a3b59797a88d485341152bf/-/blob/src/Components/Web.JS/src/Boot.Server.ts#L41:9
   await window.Blazor.reconnect();
   
   ..now it's safe to do my stuff
}
```

it 'seems' that *Blazor.reconnect()* will re-use the existing connection (if there is one)

...so it's not actually '**re**-connecting' (so 'seems' not much overhead ;-))

Answer (score 1):

I tried a setTimeout (5000 ms delay) and it worked for me.(of course it is not needed to use the setTimeout every time, just the first time).

e.g. setTimeout( DotNet.invokeMethod(...), 5000);

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a timing issue, not everything is loaded/initialized.

Have you tried putting the js code in a button onclick event?

Comment: You may have something there -- I'm getting a different error message at any rate. If this is the issue then I'm going to have to, in my Blazor component, call my JavaScript function so that it can call my C# code after everything is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

> using Microsoft.JSInterop;
>
> [Inject] protected IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

From your blazor function call this function from this method

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("fnToJavascriptCall", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
```

Create this function in blazor file

```
[JSInvokable]
        public async Task fnToCallFromJavascript(int param1, int param2)
        {
            //Do some stuff
            StateHasChanged();
        }
```

In your javascript file

```
var fnToJavascriptCall = function (param1,currentInstance)
{
    //Do your stuff
    currentInstance.invokeMethodAsync("fnToCallFromJavascript", param1, param2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `No .NET call dispatcher has been set` error can be received when the JavaScript interop is used at the wrong time. Have a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64446727/blazor-javascript-interop-no-net-call-dispatcher-has-been-set).