# Blazor - JavaScript Interop - No .NET call dispatcher has been set

Tags: c#, blazor

I am experimenting with a [Blazor WebAssembly app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.1#blazor-webassembly). When my page (i.e. index.html) loads, I want to pass a JavaScript array to the Blazor app when it loads. While trying to [call a method from JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1), I've run into an error that says:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: No .NET call dispatcher has been set
```

My code looks like this:

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>

    <script>
        let items = [
            { name:'Item 1', description:'This is a description of the first item' },
            { name:'Item 2', description:'This is a description of the second item' },
            { name:'Item 3', description:'This is a description of the third item' },
        ];

        try
        {
            DotNet
                .invokeMethodAsync('MyOrg.MyApp.Index', 'LoadItems')
                .then(results => {
                    console.log(results);
                })
            ;
        }
        catch (ex)
        {
            console.log(ex);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

**Index.razor**

```
@page "/"

@using System.Threading.Tasks;    
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

@inject ILogger<Index> logger;

<p>
    Items loaded: <span>@items.Count</span>
</p>

@code {
    List<object> items = new List<object>();

    [JSInvokable]
    private Task LoadSnippets() 
    {
        try 
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Loading items...");
            items = new List<object>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex, $"Failed to load items.");
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The first difference I noticed was that the example shown in the docs relied on a `static` method. Is this a requirement? If so, that would imply there's not a way to perform logging for example. Logging aside, even if I add `static` to the `LoadItems` method, I still get the error listed above. I don't understand why.

In short, I'm trying to create a "headless" Blazor app. I'd like to use the richness of C# to work with the data, I need to pass the results to the UI, which relies on HTML/CSS. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Blazor!

Firstly, I would suggest reading the docs at [Call .Net from js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

The way you include the script in your index.html means, that the script is executed **before** your wasm app is loaded.

To solve the issue, it is a good practice to use js interop in OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method   ([Lifecycle docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1))

So if you update your script to something like:

```
<script>
        netFromJs = {
            staticCall:  function () {
                let items = [
                    { name: 'Item 1', description: 'This is a description of the first item' },
                    { name: 'Item 2', description: 'This is a description of the second item' },
                    { name: 'Item 3', description: 'This is a description of the third item' },
                ];

                try {
                    DotNet
                        .invokeMethodAsync('wasmprerender.Client', 'LoadItems')
                        .then(results => {
                        console.log(results);
                    });
                }
                catch (ex) {
                    console.log(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Then in your component (page is also component), you will be able to do something like:

```
@inject IJSRuntime _js

@code {
    static List<object> items = new List<object>();

    [JSInvokable]
    public static Task LoadItems()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Loading items");
            items = new List<object>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("netFromJs.static");
    }
}
```

To address your note about that the static call. Your example works with the Static method call, Blazor also supports the Instance method call. You will find a nice example here [Instance call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1#instance-method-call)

Lastly, I do not recommend touch index.html too much. Create and reference separate .js file or from .NET 5 RC1 you can use [Js isolation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-release-candidate-1/#blazor-javascript-isolation-and-object-references)

Answer (score 2):

There's a way to ensure Blazor is initialized before trying to call interop

Modify your index to prevent Blazor autoloading

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js" autoload="false"></script>
```

Then you can boot Blazor yourself and use a promise to execute your interop

```
<script>
    let items = [
        { name:'Item 1', description:'This is a description of the first item' },
        { name:'Item 2', description:'This is a description of the second item' },
        { name:'Item 3', description:'This is a description of the third item' },
    ];
    window.Blazor.start()
       .then(()=>DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('MyOrg.MyApp.Index', 'LoadItems'))
       .then(results => console.log(results))
       .catch(ex=>console.log(ex));
</script>
```

Comment: It works on windows but does not work on android.

Answer (score 0):

// Error I faced

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No .NET call
> dispatcher has been set.    at m (blazor.webassembly.js:1:2655)
> at h (blazor.webassembly.js:1:2548)   at Object.e.invokeMethodAsync (blazor.webassembly.js:1:3389)   at
> HTMLDocument. (CropHelper.js:73:12)

// Solution

```
<script>
```

```
    window.Blazor.start()          
        .then(function () {
            var fileref = document.createElement('script')
            fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
            fileref.setAttribute("src", "js/CropHelper.js")
            if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
        })
        .then(results => console.log(results))
        .catch(ex => console.log(ex));

</script>
```